# After reboot KAFKA topic appears to be lost

Tags: apache-kafka

Having installed KAFKA and having looked at these posts:

1. [kafka loses all topics on reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437415/kafka-loses-all-topics-on-reboot)
2. [Kafka topic no longer exists after restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34021794/kafka-topic-no-longer-exists-after-restart)

and thus moving kafka-logs to /opt... location, I still note that when I reboot:

1. I can re-create the topic again.
2. the kafka-logs directory contains information on topics, offsets etc. but it gets corrupted.

I am wondering how to rectify this.

Testing of new topics prior to reboot works fine.

Comment: Is this a "normal" Kafka installation, or are you using a docker image like https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/ ?

Comment: @Moonwalkr   Followed this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-18-04  To me this is a normal installation

Comment: Yes. I asked bc I've noticed many who are using a docker image like that, and when they shut down the image and start it again, the installation is setup anew. Sorry I don't have an answer to your question.

Comment: thx, interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two potential problems

1. If it is kafka running in docker, then docker image restart always cleans up the previous state and creates a new cluster hence all topics are lost.
2. Check the `log.dir` or Zookeeper data path. If either is set to /tmp directory, it will be cleaned on each reboot. Hence you will lose all logs and topics will be lost.

Comment: log.dirs is set to /opt - I changed that. The link I have does not lead me to believe I am running a docker. It is a VM for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Yes, that link is for vanilla kafka installation.

Comment: The mystery continues.

Answer (score 0):

In this VM I noted the Zookeeper log was defined on /tmp. Changed that to /opt (presume it should be /var though) and the clearing of Kafka data when instance terminated was corrected. Not sure how to explain this completely.

Comment: @thebluephantom: Great. so mystery is solved now. +1

Comment: It did solve it for me. So not sure why comment was made.

Comment: Really, the review on low quality post, please.

Comment: @thebluephantom if this is how you solved your problem, mark it as accepted when you can. That will stop it appearing in the low quality post queue (which can happen automatically with very short answers) and prevent it being deleted.